# Why is my Rails Server is running an older release, instead of current?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, nginx, capistrano, passenger

I've set up my rails server using nginx, passenger, and deploy with capistrano. I've just committed/pushed my project to github and executed `cap production deploy` and everything worked normally.  However my server showed an error, when looking at the error logs it's erroring out on a line of code that is "old".  It's pointing to an earlier release and not the current release.

I've checked my passenger config (i believe it's the passenger config... in /sites-enabled/default) and the root is pointing to current/public.  Is there anything else that I can check or does anyone know why my server is using a previous release? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out there was a migration error, and I needed to correct that and then make sure my migrations ran fine.  Hope this silliness on my part helps someone else in the future.